# C++ - Sort multidimensional vector by its contained object property

Tags: c++, arrays, object, vector, sorting

I've got a bidimensional array of objects (a 2D vector containing GridCell instances) as in here:

```
typedef vector<GridCell> CellArray;
typedef vector<CellArray> TwoDCellArray;
TwoDCellArray CellArr2D;
```

I am currently drawing all the cells like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        CellArr2D[i][j].draw()
    }
}
```

However, I've got a depth problem and I should draw the instances depending on its size (size property, CellArr2D[i][j].size).

What should I do to sort this array without changing it's i,j values? Copying all the objects to a secondary array and sort that one?
And more imporntant, hence this post... how can I sort an Array (Vector) by it's contained object property?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a vector of pairs (i,j) and sort it by `size` property.

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> int_pair_t;
typedef std::vector< int_pair_t > size_index_t;

namespace {
struct sort_helper {
    sort_helper( const TwoDCellArray& arr ) : arr_(arr) {}      
    bool operator()( const int_pair_t& ind1, const int_pair_t& ind2 ) { 
      return arr_[ind1.first][ind1.second].size > arr_[ind2.first][ind2.second].size; 
    }
private:
    const TwoDCellArray& arr_;
};

struct draw_helper {
    draw_helper( TwoDCellArray& arr ) : arr_(arr) {}        
    void operator()( const int_pair_t& ind ) { 
        arr_[ind.first][ind.second].draw();
    }
private:
    TwoDCellArray& arr_;
};
}

void some_func()
{
    // initialize helper array of indices
    size_index_t index;
    index.reserve( rows*cols );
    for ( int i = 0; i < rows*cols; ++i )
        index.push_back( make_pair( i/cols%rows, i%cols ) );

    // sort according to the `size` field
    std::sort( index.begin(), index.end(), sort_helper( CellArr2D ) );

    // draw
    std::for_each( index.begin(), index.end(), draw_helper( CellArr2D ) );
}
```

Comment: I get this in Xcode
error: no matching function for call to 'sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >, Grid::update()::sort_helper)'

I tried adding #include <algorithm> but didn't work.

Comment: `sort_helper` and `draw_helper` are shouldn't be local classes in C++'03 (it is allowed only in C++0x). Move them out of your function.

Comment: Err... I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in here:
return arr_[ind1.first][ind2.second].size > arr_[ind2.first][ind2.second].size;

Comment: The cause of that error is that your `CellArr2D` doesn't contain some elements. Are you sure you have filled it with `rows*cols` elements? If no then you need to add appropriate checks in the `sort_helper`.

Comment: I'll double-check. Thank you :)

Comment: Ok. I got it working after changing the pair values.
I used a nested for loop (rows and cols).
To do it your way... Why are you using "i % cols, i / rows"? Shouldn't it be "i/cols, i % cols"? (let's say there are 6 cols... that would give us 0-0, 0-1, 0-2...)

Comment: Well, I'm getting X and Y position from a cell number. If it's cell number 6 (7th cell as it's 0-based) and there's 5 columns then X=1 and Y=1. That's why I think it's i/cols, i % cols. ANYWAY, thanks a lot for your help. You're suggested solution works great after the tweaks. :)

Comment: I've tested it. There was a bug in that loop, now I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::sort and supply a custom comparison function object to sort by a user-defined property or other relation.

As for how it should be sorted, if you want to sort it but not change it, then you will have to copy the array. The best way to do this is store your GridCells on the heap and store smart pointers to them in the vectors. This way, sorting and copying them will involve less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can put references in a secondary array and sort that one:

```
struct CellRef
{
  CellRef(GridCell& cell) : m_c(cell) {}
  bool operator<(const CellRef& r) const { return m_c.size < r.m_c.size; }
  GridCell& data() { return m_c; }
private:
  GridCell& m_c;
};

vector<CellRef> refs;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        refs.push_back(CellArr2D[i][j]);
    }
}
std::sort(refs.begin(), refs.end());
for(vector<CellRef>::iterator it=refs.begin(), end=refs.end(); it!=end; ++it)
  it->data().draw();
```